# Windows Clipboard not available

Tags: c#, .net, textbox

Help please. Problem is in Clipboard. When program starts from VS (debug), it works as expected, but if I start program direct from OS – TextDataFormat.Text and TextDataFormat.UnicodeText formats are empty strings. The same behavior occurs under VS 2008 and VS2012. I use Win 7 Home Premium (Swedish), Service Pack 1.
/Kriss

Comment: Is this a forms or web app ?

Comment: Copy and past is supported and works by default.  There is likely something interfering with the copy and past function.  How are you pasting into the textbox?

Comment: @Artur not helpful unless you elaborate!

Comment: Did you assign `Ctrl+V` as a keyboard shortcut for a menu item?

Comment: Is it a derived class or the base `TextBox` class?

Comment: What does it say next to your Main() function? STAThread or MTAThread?

Comment: Form. Ridiculous? Maybe, but it's behavies so.   No menu. I made very easy exampel only form and TextBox

Answer (score 1):

If it's `System.Windows.Forms`, maybe something sets the following based on a preprocessor directive:

```
textBox1.ShortcutsEnabled = false;
```

Wild, but it could happen. Check the MSDN [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.shortcutsenabled%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: No, shortcut prop is set to "true"

Comment: I have done more research: problem is in Clipboard. When program starts from VS (debug), it works as expected, but if I start program direct from OS – TextDataFormat.Text and TextDataFormat.UnicodeText formats are empty strings. Strange!

Answer (score 1):

It was my Anti Virus program which protected Clipboard (quietly) for "Untrusted" programs.